# JSPDF me saca páginas de más

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando imprimir un HTML en PDF con la ayuda de JSPDF, el problema es que me añade 10 páginas en blanco adicionales, siendo la primera la única válida.

Código JS:

```
 function printReport() {
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    var docPDF = new jsPDF();
    function print() {
        var elementHTML = document.querySelector("body");
        docPDF.html(elementHTML, {
            callback: function (docPDF) {
                docPDF.save('Report.pdf');
            },
            x: 15,
            y: 15,
            width: 170,
            windowWidth: 650,
            putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
        });

    }
    print();
}
```

He pensado que el problema podría estar también en el HTML que intento imprimir, que es este:

```
<div id="report" style="display: grid;grid-template-rows: 10% 60% 30%;height: 100vh;">

    <div>
        <img style="height:100px;" src="/res/logos/Logo.png" />
    </div>
    
    <div style="background-color:#1D4370;padding:1.6rem;">
        <div>
            <p style="color:white;font-weight: bold;font-size: x-large;">
                *********
            </p>
            <p style="color:white; font-size: larger;">
                @ProjectReport.Hname
            </p>
            <p style="color:white; font-size: medium;">
                Fecha del cálculo: @(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
            </p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <table class="table" style="background-color:white;">
                <thead style="background-color:#736E6E">
                    <th style="color:white;">
                        Fase
                    </th>
                    <th style="color:white;">
                        kg CO2e/m3
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Cemento
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ProjectReport.TotalCement
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Áridos
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ProjectReport.TotalArid
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Aditivos
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ProjectReport.TotalAditive
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Agua
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ProjectReport.TotalWater
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Procesos adicionales
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ProjectReport.TotalProcess
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Transportes adicionales
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @ProjectReport.TotalTransports
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p style="color:white;">
                **********
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin:2.6rem;">
        <p>
            *************
        </p>

        <p>
            ****************
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

He probado a contar el número de páginas y me pone solamente 1, sin embargo en el PDF resultante salen 10, lo que resulta aún más extraño.

Por otra parte estoy usando el framework Blazor, pero esta parte la estoy haciendo en Javascript porque pensé que sería más sencillo, aunque no creo que Blazor influya aquí de ninguna manera.

Un último problema que sucede, aunque menos importante, es que no me coge las fuentes personalizadas que tengo asignadas a las etiquetas

, y que, fuera del pdf funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Quien ejecuta la función `printReport()`?, un boton?

Comment: Se ejecuta al cargarse la página